# C++ conditional statement not being checked

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I've been scratching my head on this for a bit now and I can't seem to figure it out.

The user will enter a number between 1 and 6. I am preforming checks to ensure that the value they enter is a valid input. If it isn't it will keep prompting them until they enter in a valid input.

The issue I have is that the while loop will terminate if i enter in any integer value (which isn't what I want. The integer the user enters must be between 1 and 6, then it should exit the while loop).

I'm hoping someone can see something that I cannot. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int ReadDouble(int option) {
    while (cin.fail() != 0 && !(option > 0) && !(option <=6)) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(255, '\n');
        cerr << "Cannot read input \n";
        cout << "Choose an option between 1 and 6: " << endl;
        cin >> option;
    }
    cout << "This worked: " << endl;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int prompt = NULL;
    cout << "1. Cube" << endl;
    cout << "2. Sphere" << endl;
    cout << "3. Prism" << endl;
    cout << "4. Cylinder" << endl;
    cout << "5. Cone" << endl;
    cout << "6. Quit" << endl;
    cout << "Choose an option by typing in the corresponding number: ";
    cin >> prompt;

    ReadDouble(prompt);
}
```

Comment: Not your problem, but I'll just point this out. `!(option > 0) && !(option <=6))` can simply be `option <= 0 && option > 6`. No point in negating am operator that has an opposite.

Comment: A number cannot be both `<= 0` AND `> 6`, your condition in `while` can never be true. You probably wanted to use or (`||`) there.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thank you I am dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem as mentioned here: [C++ conditional statement not being checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57947451/c-conditional-statement-not-being-checked#comment102307993_57947451) is that you require: `!(option > 0) && !(option <=6)` A better way of doing this would be to do:

```
while(!(cin >> prompt) || prompt < 0 || prompt > 6) cout << "Cannot read input.\nChoose an option between 1 and 6: ";
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/GMU664)